# How to find multicast groups programmatically

Tags: c#, udp, multicast

Is there anyway to find IP multicast groups that have been joined on my NIC programmatically (C#)?
something like (in windows cmd)-

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

I couldn't find it..
Thanks.